# Как наиболее коротким и универсальным способом узнать установлено ли графическое окружение в Linux?

Tags: linux, gui, администрирование

Можно конечно перечислить пакеты, которые относятся к `x11`, `wayland`, `mir`, или написать длинную регулярку для `pgrep`, но хочется лаконичности.

Comment: Чтобы сделать что?

Comment: Чтобы отделить десктопы от серверов например. Ну т.е. надо ли на типичный линукс ставить Фаерфокс или не надо? Определить "факты", если говорить в терминологии ansible.

Comment: Бывают десктопы без графики, бывают серверы с графикой.

Comment: Пусть за установку фаерфокса отвечает персональная переменная в host_vars, если говорить в терминологии ansible.

Comment: Ни разу не видел десктопов без графона. Мы же щас не про `mini-tower\2U`? Не, персональная `isItLinuxWithGUI: true` - слишком "руками". Это то же самое, что запустить плейбук с параметром `--extvars`, технически можно, но не нужно.

Comment: @andreymal, тогда `systemd-detect-virt` и `ansible_virtualization_role` не нужны. И так знаем кто и зачем.

Comment: @donRumata именно так, я их никогда не использовал :)

Comment: Очень удобная штука, чтобы накатить (или не накатить) нужные guest-tools.

Comment: Мне кажется, сложная затея, и уж точно это не работает так, как в приведённом ответе. Например, у меня есть машина, на которой я каждый день запускаю firefox, gnucash и ещё пару иксовых приложений. При этом у неё видеокарты нет вообще никакой, даже встроенной. Она сервер или десктоп? Надо ли на неё ставить Хром или нет?

Comment: Вам надо уточнить вопрос, так как для программ и Xvfb вполне себе графика, а вот для пользователя -- нет.

Comment: Может по установленным пакетам типа `x11-common` посмотреть?

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну я в вопросе указал, что можно составить библиотеку гуёвых пакетов и чекать их на "установлен\неустановлен", но хочется чё-то типа `gui: true\false`. В общем смысле конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл совершенно случайно. В общем, там, где установлен `systemd` и есть какой-то гуй - есть и сервис `display-manager.service`. Пробовал на нескольких машинах - там где иксов нет - демона не существует.

Для Ansible можно делать примерно так:

```yaml
---
  - name: Run if gui is installed
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    serial:
      - "100%"
    tasks:

    - service_facts:
      when: ansible_system == 'Linux'

    - name: abc
      when:
        - ansible_system == 'Linux'
        - ansible_facts.services["display-manager.service"].state == 'active'
      command: echo 1111111111
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type   
Type=x11
```

Есть еще

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

но это работает не всегда.

**Upd:** Если дисплейный менеджер не запущен, то пишет `tty`. Спасибо  [don Rumata](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191416/don-rumata) за уточнение.
Это не работает через  Ansible, см. комментарии.

[Источник](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202891/397412).

Comment: Запустил на безгуёвом серваке - выдало `Type=tty`. Дополни ответ.

Comment: Если активных сессий нет или команда запускается за пределами сессии, то это не выведет ничего. Однако графика при этом очень даже может быть

Comment: У вайленда и мира обычно также открыты сокеты иксов

Comment: А через Ansible не работает от слова совсем: пишет `tty` даже если дисплейный менеджер вполне запущен https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX9e2.png

Comment: Или более наглядно через SSH https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKd40.png

Comment: На старых, до XDG стандарта fdo, ничего не будет.

Comment: Что делать с виртуальным X окружением (существует себе, только вывода никуда нет, тау как оно просто память), которое может использоваться для тестирования? Например, Xvfb.

Comment: Да вашужмать ((((

Comment: @ andreymal, @0andriy  А если так попрoбовать:
     `pgrep -l "x11|wayland|mir"`? Что пишет в сложных случаях?

Comment: @andreymal, А если так попрoбовать: pgrep -l "x11|wayland|mir"?

Comment: @user244413, у меня на 16-й xubuntu ничего не выдало. Но на `lightdm` отработало. Ну такое...

Comment: @don Rumata, @andreymal, @0andriy А если такое: 'ps -ef | grep " :0"`? Может, перед этим попробовать что-то графическое запустить.

Comment: @user244413, не, тогда уж просто проверить наличие установленных пакетов, которые отвечают за иксы, вяленого и мир. Я в вопросе неспроста спросил про лаконичный способ.