# Linux - определение композитора

Tags: linux

Каким образом/методом можно определить текущий запущенный/работающий композитор в системе? если неизвестен ранее установленный.

Comment: Эээ... композитор? Можно чуть подробнее что это за зверь? На линуксе сижу больше пары недель, но про композиторов слышу первый раз.

Comment: @donRumata композитор позволяет управлять различными эффектами анимации окон

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD

Как пример Sway, compiz, picom и тд

Comment: @donRumata Вот ещё. Тут больше примеров: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#Composite

Comment: А, ты про гуй. Тебе вообще зачем? Так-то - можно поискать среди запущенных юнитов Systemd. Если running/active - значит оно.

Comment: @donRumata Я вроде написал - в случае если неизвестен ранее установленный/запущенный. Кого искать то) Нужно мне это, для понимания как определить композитор в этом кейсе.

Comment: @donRumata Если я сам поставил композитор, или он идёт стандартный от какого то WM, я могу определить его название, где лежат конфиги и прочее. Меня интересует только кейс - когда условно на компе стоит compiz или picom или ещё какой либо, я этого не знаю. Как мне узнать точно какой работает? Кроме варианта с перебором всех существующих композиторов.

Comment: И поиска их в процессах

Comment: Ну или поиск установленных пакетов или поиск запущенных процессов. Других вариантов пока не придумано. Можно ещё подёргать переменные `$XDG_*`, но я бы смотрел запущенные процессы - самый надёжный способ.

Comment: Кстати! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1113754/191416

Comment: @donRumata это не то что мне нужно